# how to select random objects to display on a fixed position in adobe flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am working on a flash project and I want to select random objects from a number of objects.

For example if I have 15 objects and I want to randomly select just 4 objects and display them on the stage at fixed position.

I have searched different forums and the problems discussed on different forums are about changing the random position of objects

Note that I don't want to randomize objects position on stage I want to select random objects from multiple objects

I have no idea how to do this.
Please help me if anyone can.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet you can show as an example?

Comment: no i have not tried any thing

Answer (score 0):

You need some algorithm to get unique N objects from the object pool. For example try this one:

```
function getItemsFrom(list:Array, count:uint):Array {
    var result:Array = [];
    var needed:uint = count;
    var available:uint = list.length;
    while (result.length < count) {
        if (Math.random() < needed / available) {
            result.push(list[available - 1]);
            needed--;
        }
        available--;
    }
    return result;
}

//Simple test, and some results are: [16,9,7,5], [14,13,10,1], etc
var test:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
for(var i:uint = 0; i < 20; ++i){
    trace(getItemsFrom(test, 4));
}
```

After you will get array of objects, place them where you want.

```
//Place items vertically at (5,5);
var startX:int = 5;
var startY:int = 5;
//Vertical padding between items
var paddingY:int = 10;
//Current Y position
var posY:int = startY;
//Ger 2 random unique items from the given collection "someListWithItems"
var itemsToPlace:Array = getItemsFrom(someListWithItems, 2);
var item:DisplayObject, i:uint, len:uint = itemsToPlace.length;

for (i; i < len; ++i) {
    item = itemsToPlace[i];
    item.x = startX;
    item.y = posY;
    //Offset current position on height of object, plus padding
    posY += item.height + paddingY;
    //Add item to the display list
    addChild(item);
}
```

Comment: when i use this code it shows me
[object MovieClip],[object MovieClip]
this line 20 times in output tab may be due to loop of 20 times.

Comment: exactly explain what your code statements are doing

Comment: my objects are not numeric these are images and instances of a movieclip

Comment: It's an example how to get unique elements from the Array. You only need function `getItemsFrom`. Path array with your objects, and it will return list of unique objects.

Comment: function getItemsFrom(list:Array, count:uint):Array {
    var result:Array = [];
    var needed:uint = count;
    var available:uint = list.length;
    while (result.length < count) {
        if (Math.random() < needed / available) {
            result.push(list[available - 1]);
            needed--;
        }
        available--;
    }
    return result;
}

//Simple test, and some results are: [16,9,7,5], [14,13,10,1], etc
var test:Array = [apple1, apricot1, banana1, cherry1];
for(var i:uint = 0; i < 20; ++i){
    trace(getItemsFrom(test, 2));
}

Comment: i just change the array with my instances names and change this line
trace(getItemsFrom(test, 2)); i put here 2 instead of 4 because i want select 2 from array of 4

Comment: But `trace` is also an example. Let's go straight, at which positions (coordinates) do you want to place random fruits, and I'll provide you example.

Comment: Added example, items will be places at (5,5) one after another, vertically

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to put those objects into array, and then get random element from it.

Here is a quick example:

```
var objects:Array = new Array[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5];
var random:Object = objects.splice(int(Math.random() * objects.length), 1)[0];
```

Have in mind that these are predefined objects - you must populate the array by yourself. Another thing is that this splices the array, which means it removes items from it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andrey Popov's answer but step by step instead of one line:

```
//an array of symbols
var objects:Array = new Array(red,blue,green);

//Number you need
var needed:Number = 2;

for (var i:Number = 0;i< needed;i++){
    var randomPos = int(Math.random()*objects.length);
    //Insert fixed position here
    objects[i].x = 0;
    //remove object from array
    objects.splice(i,1); 
}
```

Comment: i use the code last one but it shows me only two objects of array on my defined position. every time i run the movie same two objects are displayed and that 2 objects are on 1st and 3rd index in my array.

Comment: i am doing this step by step
1)i add 4 png files and make them movie clip apple apricot banana and cherry.
2) i add instances of each movie on the stage and define instance name 
3) i define the action script code as follow

Comment: apple1.visible=false;
apricot1.visible=false;
banana1.visible=false;
cherry1.visible=false;


//an array of symbols
var objects:Array = new Array(apricot1, banana1, apple1, cherry1);

//Number you need
var needed:Number = 2;

for (var i:Number = 0;i< needed;i++){
    var randomPos = int(Math.random()*objects.length);
    //Insert fixed position here
    objects[i].x = 5;
 objects[i].y = 5;
 objects[i].visible = true;
    //remove object from array
    objects.splice(i,1); 
}

Comment: i hide the visibility of objects because when random 2 display on position (5,5) then all other 2 also display on stage where i create the instance of movieclip of other 2